# Add mrt package issue on MAC

Tags: node.js, git, meteor, meteorite

I need to add mrt package to meteor project using third party packages.In this i install npm and meteorite but adding packages to meteor project in this time gets the below error :

```
 mrt add router
```

Error  :

```
✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.6.1
ERROR: 128 Command failed: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git


STDOUT:  

STDERR: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git



/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:181
            self.checkoutType + ": " + (self.commit || self.head);
                                     ^
There was a problem checking out tag: v0.6.1
```

I am new to Meteor.So ididn't get any idea about this error.Please suggest me what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

`router` is a deprecated package.

Use `iron-router` instead:

```
mrt add iron-router
```

See its [Github page](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-iron-router) for basic documentation.